# Memory debugger for linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Is there any memory debugger for linux kernel?
We have issues with "NULL pointer dereference" kernel oops among other crashes on android/linux arm based hardware.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Modern kernels contain a great deal of built-in diagnostic tools (those are available in "Kernel hacking" sub-menu of the kernel source configuration tool). However, on embedded targets one has also an option of using gdb with a good jtag debugger, such as Abatron BDI series (this will, of course, allow for the most precise diagnostics, including diagnostics of interrupt related problems).

In the absence of hardware debugger, the following options can be quite handy to detect memory leaks (don't forget to compile the kernel with "Compile the kernel with debug info" and "Compile the kernel with frame pointers" set):

1. **Kernel memory leak detector** - useful in catching kmalloc/kfree errors.
2. **KGDB** (with suboptions) - this will enable a built-in gdb server inside the kernel, which can be accessed from a gdb front-end over a serial port. There's also a KGDB_KDB option to do the same manually (by omitting the gdb front end and using a human manageable protocol).
3. **kmemcheck** - requires the least of human interaction and the most machine resources, but can be handy in doing initial memory related problem analysis.

There are plenty of other diagnostics options, useful with more specific classes of problems. Most of them are reasonably documented both with kernel configuration tool snippets as well as with separate documents in Documentation/ sub-directory of the source (+ various online publications).

Comment: I actually have JTAG debugger for the arm board. How would you approach NULL pointer issues with JTAG?

Comment: Also, I checked about kmemcheck, but it may not be available for ARM arch. Any idea?

Comment: There is no such thing as "NULL pointer issues". What you've got is either broken software or broken hardware (RAM timing issues, etc). The later can be diagnosed with user space tools or hw debugger (load/unload big chunks of data taking care to hit the possibly problematic memory bank). The former is to be fixed the usual way: printouts, breakpoints and isolation (starting with minimal kernel config and incrementally adding features).